how to dynamic switch theme, angular material 18
I have created 2 custom themes using angular material utility. ng generate @angular/material:m3-theme.
I use both themes in styles.scss like this.
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@use './m3-theme';
@use './m4-theme';
@include mat.core();
.alternate-theme-m3 {
        @include mat.core-theme(m3-theme.$light-theme);
        @include mat.button-theme(m3-theme.$light-theme);
        background-color: mat.get-theme-color(m3-theme.$light-theme, secondary, 50) !important;
    }
    
    .alternate-theme-m4 {
        @include mat.core-theme(m4-theme.$light-theme);
        @include mat.button-theme(m4-theme.$light-theme);
        background-color: mat.get-theme-color(m4-theme.$light-theme, secondary, 50) !important;
    }

And in my component i am toggling the class to get styles.
Q1: Is this correct approach, or any better way to apply custom these, and dynamic theme switching.
Q2: mat-button are coming very round, I could not make it little round. How can I acheive that?
Thanks.

example below:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
export enum ColorScheme {
  Deep_Purple_And_Amber = 'deeppurple-amber.css',
  Indigo_And_Pink = 'indigo-pink.css',
  Pink_And_Bluegrey = 'pink-bluegrey.css',
  Purple_And_Green = 'purple-green.css',
}


@Injectable()
export class ColorSchemeService {
  public currentColorScheme: ColorScheme|null = null;
  private key = 'colorScheme';

  initColorScheme(): void {
    const localColorScheme = localStorage.getItem(this.key) as ColorScheme;
    this.changeColorScheme(localColorScheme || ColorScheme.Deep_Purple_And_Amber);
  }

  changeColorScheme(colorScheme: ColorScheme): void {
    if (this.currentColorScheme === colorScheme) return;
    localStorage.setItem(this.key, colorScheme);
    const oldElement = document.getElementById(this.key);
    if (oldElement) oldElement.remove();
    this.currentColorScheme = colorScheme;
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    const link = document.createElement('link');
    link.id = this.key;
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = 'assets/css/material/' + colorScheme;
    head.insertBefore(link, head.lastChild); // обязательно после style.css чтобы переопределялись цвета все

    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.classList.add(colorScheme.replace('.css', ''));
  }
}

you need to place somewhere your themes (after serve\build) and change little bit code (path, file names and init function default value). All clients will not use 2 or more themes at same time, so each theme should be in its own file.
in my angular.json:
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "*.css",
    "input": "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/",
    "output": "assets/css/material/"
  }
],

